# Why my nested table with collapsible rows is not displaying correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable

I am trying to implement a nested table with collapsible rows but its not showing correctly. Here is my JavaScript:

```js
<script>
function fnFormatDetails(table_id, html) {
    var sOut = "<table id=\"exampleTable_" + table_id + "\">";
    sOut += html;
    sOut += "</table>";
    return sOut;
}
var iTableCounter = 1;
var oTable;
var oInnerTable;
var TableHtml;

$(document).ready(function() {
    TableHtml = $("#exampleTable").html();            
    var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
    var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
    nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">';
    nCloneTd.className = "center";
    $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function() {
        this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
    });
    $('#exampleTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
    });            
    var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [0]
        }],
        "aaSorting": [
            [1, 'asc']
        ]
    });
    $('#exampleTable tbody td img').live('click', function() {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {                   
            this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
        } else {                   
            this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
            oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details');
            oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
            iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**And here is the HTML table I am displaying:**

```html
<table id="exampleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>March</td>
            <td>$80</td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**links I am using for the scripts and styling:**

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't display any table at all, just plain text in rows.
Any idea whats wrong here?

P.S. I am using the code from this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DoDSoftware/WwDg8/820/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the main reference to the jquery script first.  This was missing from your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then your table will appear to be formatted correctly.

Next, you have an error for the image click.  Convert the .live() function to an .on() function, since .live() has been removed from jquery 1.9 and onwards.

```
        $('#exampleTable').on('click', 'tbody td img', function() {
```

Here is the complete code, no errors in Firefox 78.0.1

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="exampleTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Month</th>
                        <th>Savings</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2012</td>
                        <td>January</td>
                        <td>$100</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2012</td>
                        <td>February</td>
                        <td>$80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2012</td>
                        <td>March</td>
                        <td>$80</td>
                    </tr>                        
                </tbody>
            </table>

<script>
    function fnFormatDetails(table_id, html) {
        var sOut = "<table id=\"exampleTable_" + table_id + "\">";
        sOut += html;
        sOut += "</table>";
        return sOut;
    }
    var iTableCounter = 1;
    var oTable;
    var oInnerTable;
    var TableHtml;
   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        TableHtml = $("#exampleTable").html();            
        var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
        var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
        nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">';
        nCloneTd.className = "center";
        $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function() {
            this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
        });
        $('#exampleTable tbody tr').each(function() {
            this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
        });            
        var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                "bSortable": false,
                "aTargets": [0]
            }],
            "aaSorting": [
                [1, 'asc']
            ]
        });
        //$('#exampleTable tbody td img').live('click', function() {
        $('#exampleTable').on('click', 'tbody td img', function() {
            var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {                   
                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            } else {                   
                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
                oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details');
                oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                });
                iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its still the same problem

Comment: it looks even worse, I think you are missing something in your code. Try uploading your entire code to jsffidle

Comment: I changed the http references to https, see if that works for you now.

Comment: How can I actually have rows with just a values (for ex. name) and after expanding show more information about that name? How can I implement that?

Comment: Try this out:  https://jsfiddle.net/baumli/mkhpeLow/  You'll need to create a new table, then reference that in the expand code.  This is only showing 1 table, but you'll need to create one for each record you want to expand to.